# Firefox marketplace: manifest file validation

Tags: manifest, firefox-os

I am trying to submit an app as packaged app to the firefox marketplace. The code is hosted on github at the address https://github.com/dacapito/ebac/ .

When running the manifest validator I get the following errors

---

Your app failed validation with 2 errors.

- JSON Parse Error

  ### *  Manifests must be served with the HTTP header "Content-Type: application/x-web-app-manifest+json".

and looking to the error details:

---

- Error: The webapp extension could not be parsed due to a syntax error
  in the JSON

  No JSON object could be decoded: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

---

I have tested my manifest file with a json validator and it gave no problems. And moreover the very same app was submitted to the marketplace as a packaged app and the validator gave no problems at all..

Could it be a server trouble (not serving the file with the correct content) or what else ?

regards

Comment: It might be caused by the `tab` char. Try replacing them with spaces instead.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Remove this part

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8">
```

and retire  manifest="manifest.appcache" because is for hosted apps

```
 <html manifest="manifest.appcache">  for 
 <html>
```

Comment: I applied all the suggestions of Loic and Osgux but the error (unchanged) is still there...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to create a hosted app, not a packaged app isnt?

In that case you can serve your app from github, but you need to follow github rules to create the project github pages, more information [here](http://pages.github.com/).

Fortunately, git pages recognise the extension .webapp and will server with the correct content type.

You have a whole article by Margaret Leibovic on how to use github pages for your FirefoxOS application [here](http://blog.margaretleibovic.com/post/42380607377/hacking-firefox-os-apps-with-github-pages).

Comment: Dear francisco  thanks infinitely for your suggestions. Actually , (though after some toiling..) I succeeded in passing the validation tests. Cheers